# Disable zoom but retrieve scroll on foreignObject

Tags: d3.js, angularjs-directive

I am using d3.js + AngularJS to create a tree.
The tree is zoomable, a behaviour I achieved doing the following (as recomended in the doc - please note I am using v3 : [https://devdocs.io/d3~3/zoom-behavior.md#zoom](https://devdocs.io/d3%7E3/zoom-behavior.md#zoom)) :

```
let zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([.5, 2])
    .on("zoom", function() {
        svg.attr("transform",  "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ") scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    });

svg = d3.select(".tree-div")
    .append("svg")
    .call(zoom)
    .append("g");
```

Recently, I added tooltips on nodes of my tree. The tooltips are generated in an Angular directive.

```
d3.selectAll(".tree-node").append("g")
    .classed("tree-node-tooltip", true)
    .call(function() {
         $compile(this[0])($scope);
    });
```

These tooltips are composed of a bar chart + a foreignObject that should be a scrollable div. However I never managed to have the foreignObject drop the zooming behaviour and retrieve the scrolling one.

I saw a few posts stating similar problems, but none of the solutions I found worked for me. I tried the following:

## Disabling the zoom directly on the tooltips

Using a variety of :

- `.("zoom", null)`
- `.(".zoom", null)`
- `.("wheel.zoom", null)`
- `.("mousewhell.zoom", null)`

after `.attr("classed", "tree-node-tooltip")`. The zooming behaviour is maintained.

## Filter on the zoom handler

```
.on("zoom", function() {
    if (mouse is over tooltip) {
        return;
    }
    svg.attr("transform",  "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
});
```

This disables the zooming but also the native scrolling.

I also tried to stop propagation of event (on `zoom`, on `zoomstart`), no effect (zooming remained).

Do you have any idea how I could do this? I am completely stuck here. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried stopping the event to propagate on tooltips? `...call(...).on("wheel", function() { d3.event.preventDefault(); })`

Comment: I assumes you meant `d3.event.stopPropagation`... and it _worked_, thank you so much! Amazing how only a few lines of code can change a lot.I thought I had done this, guess I did not put is on the right spot... 
You should publish an answer so that I can accept it :)

Comment: Added the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a listener for on a D3 Selection where you can stop the event propagation as such:

```
d3
 .selectAll(...)
 .call(...)
 .on("wheel", 
    function() { 
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
    })
```

Comment: `d3.event.preventDefault();` should not be there though, as it would prevent default action on mousewheel - scrolling.